# Data Received from RS232 COM1 port is coded form like Sqares

Tags: serial-port, vb.net-2010

I am doing a project where i have to Interface to a serial device through RS232 COM1 port. I have set the BAUDRATE=9600, PORT=COM1, PARITY=None, Databits=8 but when I start to read data from the serial device it appears only series of square charecters. 
I am working with VB.NET 2010
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're reading the data properly -- if you know you're only going to be receiving hexadecimal bytes then you should be using the function `Read(Byte(), Int32, Int32)`, which reads hexadecimal data.

Also, make sure your baud rate in your code matches the devices baud rate.  Otherwise, you'll get strange data bytes.